# Tensor product of fundamental representation of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ as submodule and decomposition of elements

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

Lets consider the Lie group $\mathrm{SU}(2)$. It is well-known that there is for every half-integer $j\in\mathbb{N}_{0}/2$ a unique irreducible and unitary representation of dimension $2j+1$, which I denote by $V_{j}$. Using the famous decomposition theorem of Clebsch-Gordan, which states that
$$V_{j_{1}}\otimes V_{j_{2}}\cong V_{\vert j_{1}-j_{2}\vert}\oplus V_{\vert j_{1}-j_{2}\vert+1}\oplus\dots\oplus V_{j_{1}+j_{2}}$$

one can show by induction that the module $V_{j}$ can be viewed as a submodule of $V_{1/2}^{\otimes 2j}$, where $V_{1/2}$ is the fundamental representation. Now, does anyone know how this inclusion acts on a basis?

More precisely, consider the standard basis of $V_{1/2}$, which in physics terminology, is usually denoted as
$$\vert\uparrow\rangle:=\bigg\vert\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\bigg\rangle$$ $$\vert\downarrow\rangle:=\bigg\vert\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\bigg\rangle$$
Now, lets take some arbitrary element $\vert z\rangle\in V_{1/2}$, which we can write as
$$\vert z\rangle=c_{1}\vert\uparrow\rangle+c_{2}\vert\downarrow\rangle$$

Then, I can consider the elements $\vert z\rangle^{\otimes 2j}$ as an element of $V_{j}$. How can I decompose $\vert z\rangle^{\otimes 2j}$ in terms of the standard basis of $V_{j}$, i.e.
$$\{\vert j,m\rangle\}_{-j\leq m\leq j}?$$

Comment: Perhaps I am confused, but by the Clebsch--Gordan formula $V_{1/2} \otimes V_{1/2} \cong V_0 \oplus V_1$ which is not a submodule of $V_1$. More generally $V_{1/2}^{\otimes j}$ is $2^j$-dimensional while $V_j$ is $(2j + 1)$-dimensional so it never fits for dimension reasons.

Comment: Srry there was a typo. Its the other way round... See edit